# Updating an entry in an ASP.net SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-update

Using an SQLDataSource, how do I update entries by the uniqueID key?  It's a simple question but I am soooo confused!  I need to edit a value named "pageContent".  It is the value that I need to update!

Cheers!

**EDIT**

This ones for you Jorge:

> [key] id/int (No Nulls)
>
> ```
>   pageContent/nvarchar(MAX) (No Nulls)
> ```

*Current Content:*

> [ id ] [ pageContent ]
>
> 1        `<b>test</b>`
>
> 2      test

Comment: What control you are using for updating? I mean DetailsView/FormView/GridView ?

Comment: hi, could you please post your data base table.

Comment: @Muhammad, my data is being changed inside of a FormView.

Comment: @Jorge I'll edit my post in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlDataSource is used to bind database data to controls on web page and not to preform direct operations on database.

If you just need to update one column in table on given key, consider using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection class to connect to db and System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand class to execute sql statement.

EDIT:
Example of use very similar to your case is in SqlCommand.Parameters help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Comment: ok, Thanks!  Quick question though, what does a connection string look like?  I saved one using my SQLDataSource (I'll just use that CS) but what other stuff is in the string?

Comment: See www.connectionstrings.com for details on what's in a connection string and how to make one for any given datasource.